Building iPXE with HTTPS support
I created certs usign acme.sh (lets encrypt) for my home openwrt router.
In the end it reported
[Fri Nov 29 18:xx:xx UTC 2024] The intermediate CA cert is in: /root/.acme.sh/somefqdn_ecc/ca.cer
[Fri Nov 29 18:xx:xx UTC 2024] And the full chain certs is there: /root/.acme.sh/somefqdn_ecc/fullchain.cer

I converted the certs to DER and configured uHTTPd. The Chrome reports certificate is valid if I open luci or attempt to download via https file https://somefqdn/isos/undionly.kpxe
Then I tried to do build of iPXE source https://github.com/ipxe/ipxe.git
Tried for commit 4f7dd7fbba205d413cf9b989f7cdc928fa02caf2 and for a3f1e8fb6707811e6eb90e339d7ebe813fd89a63
By running
make bin/ipxe.usb TRUST=$trustca CERT=$trustcert DEBUG=open,httpcore

where $trustca is the file of The intermediate CA /root/.acme.sh/somefqdn_ecc/ca.cer,
$trustcert is  the full chain certs is there: /root/.acme.sh/somefqdn_ecc/fullchain.cer
Note I use PEM certs(as documentation says) exactly as I get them from acme.sh, but not converted to DER certs.
The build completes ok.(For a3f1e8fb6707811e6eb90e339d7ebe813fd89a63 have to use distrobox image with fedora 32 and old  gcc, make etc, etc to avoid new compiler errors )
When I execute in KVM VM machine with content bin/ipxe.usb ( I run dd to write  into virtual hdd drive) I get next(I get same problem if I fash bin/ipxe.usb to USB and try on a real machine)
iPXE> imgfetch https://somefqdn/isos/undionly.kpxe

INTF Oxefe24+18 opening https URI
https://somefqdn/isos/undionly.kpxe...INTF Oxf0544+18 opening (SOCK_DGRAM,AF_UNKNOWN) socket
INTF ©xf01?4+50 opening (SOCK_STREAM,AF_INET) socket
Error: x420c6001 (http://ipxe.org/420c6001)
iPXE> imgfetch https://boot.ipxe.org/1mb
INTF @xef6b4+18 opening https URI
‘boot.ipxe.org/Imb...INTF Oxeffd4+18 opening (SOCK_DGRAM,AF_UNKNOWN) sock

INTF @xefca4+50 opening (SOCK_STREAM,AF_INET) socket
INTF @xef9?4+18 opening URI http://ca.ipxe.org/auto/c9Zeb62f.der?subject=MEBxCzA
JBGNUBAYTA LUTHSkuJuYDUQQKEYBIbnk lcm 14CBTZWN1cm] GeSBSZXN1YXU jaCBHem9 1cDEUMBMGA1U
EAXMMSUNSRYBSb2901F gx

INTF @xef974+18 opening http URI

INTF ©xf@bc4+*18 opening (SOCK_DGRAM,AF_UNKNOWN) socket

INTF ©xf@0a4+10 opening (SOCK_STREAM,AF_INET) socket

Permission denied (http://ipxe.org/0Z16eb3c)

What do I do wrong? How I can build it to make it work with HTTPS? I have enabled the proposed DEBUG options but nothing helps to understand what is going on.
It feels like download happens as it outputs dots like it downloads something before shows and error and then at the end some error appears.

The problem was caused that generated certificates were ECC, while iPXE currently doesn't support ECC(work in progress) once regenerated certs to use RSA it started to work using https.
